# Why would Tomcat STDOUT Always Point to /dev/null?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

We're happily running three CentOS servers, each with the same application deployed on a Tomcat instance (UAT, Demo and Production). We use Log4j in the application to output to the standard CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out file. This works perfectly on the UAT and Demo servers, but on the Production server we get output in this file up till the end of the startup process, but none of the application logging is ever output.

Using LSOF I can see that the STDOUT always winds up pointing to /dev/null. Even when explicitly starting Tomcat with >> $CATALINA_OUT 2>&1 & appended to it, it winds up pointing at /dev/null. I can see on the other servers it points to the correct catalina.out file.

I have re-deployed tomcat on the server, and have directly copied the config files from the working UAT instance, and I'm now scratching my head. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

How are you "starting Tomcat with >> $CATALINA_OUT 2>&1 & appended to it" ?

Are you 100% sure no one has modified `bin/startup.sh` or `bin/catalina.sh` to add the `/dev/null` behavior?

Unrelated to your core question, but I would strongly suggest using a log4j configuration to write to a file (`FileAppender`) rather than logging to standard out - this gives you options to roll the files over based on the date/size/etc, change the location, etc, very easily. Logging to standard out does not give you this flexibility.

Comment: I grabbed the full process name from ps which includes all of the switches and options, then explicitly put >> /opt/server/logs/catalina.out 2>&1 & at the end - basically emulating what the startup.sh does.  I am sure that the startup & catalina scripts have not been edited, as we did a fresh Tomcat install on the server in case something like that had happened. I agree with you on the proper logging config, however we still have a bunch of exceptions that just route to STDOUT at the moment, and need to capture these while we refactor the logging in the application.

Comment: Are you installing Tomcat from a package someone built, or from a distribution from the official site?

Comment: It's the vanilla install from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar setup that does work correctly; the thing to do is to find out what's different about the one that doesn't. Do a diff on the following files:

- conf/logging.properties
- bin/startup.sh
- bin/catalina.sh

Also compare:

- The user that owns the Tomcat process, and the groups that the user belongs to.
- File ownership and permissions on the logging directory.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've already checked on these, and in fact replaced the logging.properties and startup/shutdown/catalina shell scripts with ones from a known-good server. To eliminate user rights issues, Tomcat on all three servers is run as root, with the whole tomcat directory owned by root:root. I have checked the permissions on the logging directory also, and these match across the servers. The odd thing is that the STDERR still points to catalina.out.